# Cannot install ADB driver for Android Device

Tags: drivers, android, adb

I have an **Alcatel Pixi 4 (7")** tablet and I would like to **install the ADB** (Android Debug Bridge) for it because I would like to develop android apps.

I have already tried many links in google, the best match is:

http://gsmusbdriver.com/alcatel-pixi-4-7

Which have the ADB driver.

Unfortunately if I try to install this driver my system immediately pops an error that the **driver not working correctly, error code 10.**

I have also googled this error and Microsoft's support page said that this is a **very general error** which means the driver cannot be installed correctly, could not got any closer to the solution.

So I searched more and I have found a software called **'ADB Universal driver'**

http://adbdriver.com/

This is basically, a driver manager for any android device, sadly this is not listing my Pixi 4, so it **could not download any adb driver** for it.

I have found 3 different versions from this software, **tried all of them, same error in each version.**

**Please note:** My PC does see the device as a connected device, I can transport files, etc. So the USB driver is working correctly, I just need the ADB driver which is a different thing.

If you have any suggestion please help me out. This is nonsense that I bought a device which is **released in 2016, It has Android 6.1** which is almost the most recent version and I cannot make work a should-be-simple adb driver for it.

It's nonsense in the first place that I have to install the **official driver as "Legacy driver"** like this thing coming from Windows XP.

My System is Windows 8.1

Device: [Pixi 4 (7")](http://www.gsmarena.com/alcatel_pixi_4_(7)-7847.php)